# How to fix this form validations in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6

1. When I type username it shows errors all the time unless I provide characters, symbols, and numbers altogether. While I need to let users choose different combinations. For example only characters, characters with numbers, characters with symbols, only numbers, numbers with symbols and so on. At the moment it requires altogether.
2. For name field, I need to require only characters and don't let users submit numbers or symbols. The issues are in `validators.pattern`

Here is the code which works wrong:

```
 this.RegisterForm = new FormGroup({
    'username': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
       Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])'),]),
    'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
       Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])'),]),
     ...
     ...
})
```

How can I fix these 2 form's `validators.patterns`?

Comment: What do you need to restrict the user for `username`?

Comment: I need to let users choose different combinations. For example only characters, characters with numbers, characters with symbols, only numbers, numbers with symbols and so on. At the moment it requires altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only numbers, this is the way: `Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]*$/)`.

And for the username: `Validators.pattern(/^[a-z0-9A-Z._]+$/i)`

Answer (score 0):

For `name` use `^[a-z]+$` and for 'username' use `^[a-z0-9A-Z._]+$`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try it today and let you know :)